# Does while loop have two Arguments?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, g++

My ma'am gave me one question to solve. To predict the output of the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    printf("Output is : ");
    while (i < 5, j < 10)    // Doubt: how does while accept 2 arguments?? and how it works??
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
}
```

I thought it was a syntax error. But when I tried to run, it gave me output.

```
Output is : 10, 10
```

But How? Can anyone explain?

But if I remove the first printf statement `printf("Output is : ");` and run it, my antivirus give me a alert that a `Trojan` is detected.
But how it becomes a `Trojan`?

Comment: see [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: to explain you have to know how "," operator works.

if you do 

x =  m,n ; //it will take value of m

if you do 

x= (m,n); // it will take the value of n because of parenthesis.

Comment: "while(i<5,j<10)" means perform "i<5" and then perform "j<10". the overall result of expressions separated by the comma operator is the value of the right-most expression. so, the line becomes "while(j<10)". "i<5" is useless here.

Comment: if I remove the `printf` statement and run it, my antivirus give me a alert that a `trojan` is detected.

Comment: That's probably just flawed Antivirus heuristic, nothing relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1136117/3496666

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is a binary operator and it evaluates its first operand and discards the result, it then evaluates the second operand and returns this value.

so in your case,

```
First it will increment i and j upto 5 and discard.
Second it will iterate i and i upto 10 and provide you the result as 10, 10.
```

you can confirm by using the following code,

```
while (i < 5, j < 10)    // Doubt: how does while accept 2 arguments?? and how it works??
{
    i++;
    j+ = 2;
}
```