# While loop go into infinite loop when 0,1

Tags: while-loop, infinite-loop

Why this code does not print awesome

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while (1, 0) {
        cout << "awesome\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this code prints awesome Infinite times

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while (0, 1) {
        cout << "awesome\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ compiler

Answer (score 2):

because the while loop doesn't care about the first part of your expression.

```
#include<iostream>
   using namespace std;

int main(){
   while(0 <- ,1){cout<<"awesome\n";}
   return 0;
}
```

This part will be ignored. Compile your code with -Wall.

If this part will be ignored, the code is false in the first example and true in the last example.

Comment: it does care about the first part, it just doesn't use the result. If you had an int and incremented it here, it would work

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the while-expression does not care about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using the comma operator ([Does while loop have two Arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133845/does-while-loop-have-two-arguments)) which evaluates the first operand (before comma) and returns the second.

Which means that in your first loop, you're doing `while(0)`, and 0 is evaluated to `false` (immediatly ends). And in your second your doing `while(1)`, and 1 is evaluated to `true` (infinite loop).