# Assigning values in while condition

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements, infinite-loop, infinite

First of all I know what is difference between = and ==. I want to use = to implicitly make infinite loop.
So my code looks like this:

```
 boolean flag= true;
    while (flag=false){
        System.out.println("inside loop");
    }
    System.out.println("rest");
```

Unfortunately it doesn't enter the loop and prints "rest". Why? Am I reading this wrong?
In while condition I am assigning value false to flag. So it loops while flag=false (which is).

And when I do this(changed from false to true) it enters infinite loop:

```
boolean flag= true;
    while (flag=true){
        System.out.println("inside loop");
    }
    System.out.println("rest");
```

In my opinion both of these examples should enter the loop. But only the 1st one does. Please help me understand this. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136108/assigning-value-in-while-loop-condition
maybe this link can help you

Comment: Are you trying to both assign false to flag and test if it's false at the same time?

Comment: No, I am trying to figure out why the code doesn't enter the loop in both cases :(

Comment: i really don t understand what are you looking in this question, but if you want to enter in a loop with your first example, why don t you do this `while ((flag=false)==false)`

Comment: Interesting. I' ll accept an answer that helps me. Sorry I am new to stack, so didn't know about that option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (flag=false)` does two things:

1. It assigns `false` to `flag`
2. It evaluates to `while(false)`

Since it evaluates to `while(false)`, its body will not be executed.

**Similarly,**

`while (flag=true)` does two things:

1. It assigns `true` to `flag`
2. It evaluates to `while(true)`

Since it evaluates to `while(true)`, its body will be executed infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way assignment operators works.

In your loop condition you are stating

```
flag = true
```

Which returns `true`, but before that is assigns `true` to `flag`

This is because we are allowed do multiple assignments at once like this:

```
boolean test = flag = true;
// test == true
```

essentially `(flag = true)` translates to:

- assign true to flag
- return `true` for further use

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. Essentially the most important thing is that flag = false RETURNS FALSE. Which then easily means that it doesn't enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first step your while loop test does is

```
flag=false
```

immediately followed by testing its value, which is false.

On a false value, the while loop isn't entered.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between = and == is :

- = is an assignment operator, you give the value to the int, boolean, or whatever is the constant / variable.
- == is an operator, which is used mainly in loops (for, else for, if, and while)

For your case, I might say that you need to use == inside the while loop :

```
boolean flag=true;
    while (flag==false){
        System.out.println("inside loop");
    }
    System.out.println("rest");
```

It is also not great to use an infinite loop. You won't go outside and it will bug your code.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know that. I want to make infinite on purpose. My question is why it doesn't enter the loop in both cases. Do you know why?